# Rails: updating password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I want to allow users to update their password only if they know their old password. Currently I allow users to update their password without checking their old pass. Can you point me in the right direction.

Current user update method:

```
def update
  if params[:user][:password] 
    if current_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been changed!"
      else
        render "edit" 
      end
    else
      # Something else
    end
  end 
end
```

(HAML) Current form:

```
= form_for @user do |f|  
  - if @user.errors.any?
    - for message in @user.errors.full_messages
      = message
  .form
    = f.password_field :password
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation
    %input{name: "commit", type: "submit", value: "SAVE CHANGES"}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, what happens to users who have forgotten their old password?

Comment: ^ there is another option for that but I left it out of the update controller here. I'm trying to figure it out solo now.

Answer (score 1):

in controller

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:current_password]) &&
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
  ...
```

in user model

```
def authenticate(password)
  # whatever you have to do to check if the password matches the current password
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a technique inspired from the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem.

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb:**

```
def update
  @user.update_with_password(user_params)
  ...
end
```

**app/models/user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :current_password

  def update_with_password(user_params)
    current_password = user_params.delete(:current_password)

    if self.authenticate(current_password)
      self.update(user_params)
      true
    else
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end
  end
end
```

This sets an validation error if the current password is missing or incorrect.

**Note:** I'm using has_secure_password for the authenticate method, but you can change it to whatever you like.

Comment: If `self.update(user_params)` fails, the method still returns `true`. So instead of returning `true` it should just return the response from `self.update(user_params)`.